# Exporting a question from Stack Overflow for Teams to public

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Can I make a question (which I posted in our private company-related Stack Overflow for Teams space) public on Stack Overflow — or export it if I don't get a sufficient answer, or do I have to create a new question on the public site?

Comment: Copy & Paste are your friends. Although I would imagine the question needs to be tailored for a general audience, wouldn't it?

Comment: This is a valid and reasonable support question, not a FR or discussion. I’m sorry it’s been downvoted so much. Joy’s answer is correct. To help protect the privacy of internal content, we don’t have a way to make a Teams post public. There’s other reasons for this, too, but asking it manually is the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't automatically export from Stack Overflow for Teams to the public site.

You can copy and paste your question into Stack Overflow. I'd recommend that you review the [suggestions for how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chances of it receiving an answer.